# Python: Adding an empty list as value to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to append an empty list as the value when the name_input is not empty and grade_input is empty to a dictionary, whose keys are the name_input. The following is the code snippet. But it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
if (name_input != '' and grade_input ==''):
        name_dic[name_input].append([])
```

Comment: You don't append to a dictionary. Just do this: `name_dic[name_input] = []`

Comment: Do you have only one grade_input for each name_input? A dict of empty lists doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: If you're trying to initialize as an empty list, you can try using a `defaultdict` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.append()` method applies to lists, not dictionaries.

To add a new key/value pair to a dictionary, simply do this:

```
name_dic[name_input] = []
```

Comment: As ldjaw commented earlier.

Comment: You don't necessarily need square brackets on the right side of assignment when assigning values.